# Combine two rows into one string

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have dynamic database, and i want to search in this table

```
FieldID | Content | TypeID
--------------------------
ABC-123 | jon     | 1
EFG-456 | doe     | 1
HIJ-789 | man     | 1
```

So my SELECT query looks something like this:

```
SELECT 
    GROUP_CONCAT(fieldsContent.Content SEPARATOR '|*|') AS Content, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(fieldsContent.FieldID SEPARATOR '|*|') AS FieldID, 
FROM (`customers`) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `fieldsContent` ON `fieldsContent`.`TypeID` = `customers`.`ID` 
GROUP BY `fieldsContent`.`TypeID` 
ORDER BY `customers`.`Created` DESC
```

And the result looks like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Content] => jon|*|doe|*|man
            [FieldID] => ABC-123|*|EFG-456|*|HIJ-789
        )
)
```

And when i'm adding HAVING and searching only for `jon`, it will return me the result

```
HAVING Content LIKE "%jon%"
```

But, when i'm trying to search `jon doe` it will return empty result

```
HAVING Content LIKE "%jon doe%"
```

Because `jon doe` don't exists in the string, only `jon|*|doe`

So how can i combine these two rows to one string without the SEPARATOR for me the search in them `jon doe` ?

BUT!! keep in mind that i need to obtain the SEPARATOR because i need to combine the data to be used in php.

ex:

```
$field = explode('|*|',$data->FieldID);
$content = explode('|*|',$data->Content);

foreach($field as $k => $FieldID){
    switch($FieldID){
        case 'ABC-123':
            $res['first_name'] = $content[$k];
        break;
        case 'EFG-456':
            $res['last_name'] = $content[$k];
        break;
        case 'HIJ-789':
            $res['gender'] = $content[$k];
        break;      
    }
}
```

Any ideas will be appreciated :)

Comment: Is having a space as separator instead of |*| an option?

Comment: @EndeNeu No because in the data can be space and it will mess up everything

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## TRY THIS #1

```
HAVING Content LIKE "%jon%doe%"
```

## TRY THIS #2

```
HAVING Content LIKE "%jon" AND Content LIKE "%doe%"
```

## TRY THIS #3

```
HAVING REPLACE(Content,'|*|',' ') LIKE "%jon doe%"
```

## GIVE IT A TRY !!! :-)

Comment: I almost down voted this as it didn't have GIVE IT A TRY!! at the bottom

Comment: The first one suited the best. Thanks for the simple answer :)

Answer (score 1):

**Use:-**

HAVING Content LIKE "%jon%" AND Content LIKE "%doe%"

Comment: see the answer above, `HAVING Content LIKE "%jon%doe%"` suited for me the best

Comment: HAVING Content LIKE "%jon%doe%" assumes that doe would always follow joe. My answer has no assumptions regarding at what place jon or doe comes

Comment: Thats another good point of view, there is no such thing a bad advice. Thanks !